# Memory leak with WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have met a memory leak below:

[image]

I just have no idea why the WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager can cause this memory leak. I didn't find any useful info after googling. Has anyone met this?

Comment: did you resolved this case? any insights?

Comment: Not sure what causes this issue. I explicitly dismissed the dialog shown in the activity in onDestroy, avoided passing activity to the layoutinflater. The issue is gone, but not sure if the dialog is the root cause.

Comment: I bet it is not, because I'm very shure that I'm not showing any dialogs when leak occur (if any - I'm using `DialogFragment`, which is just a `Fragment` with `Dialog` styling). Thats the most common resolution for this leak after some search, but it's not for my case... :/ What you are passing to `LayoutInflater`, which `Context`? Maybe got from any `View`? It should be same, but maybe on newer devices it is wrapped up into other class, maybe this is a cause in my code?